# has_many through form driven by checkboxes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

Models : based on [rails 3 guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)!

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :physician_specialities
  has_many :specialities, :through => :physician_specialities
end

class speciality < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :physician_specialities
  has_many :physicians, :through => :physician_specialities
end

class PhycianSpeciality < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

And the database schema looks like this :

```
Physician
  id
  name
Speciality
  id
  name
PhycianSpeciality
  id
  physician_id
  speciality_id
  description
```

I want to have a form which is able to add specialities to a physician and write a small description of this speciality (according to the physician).

I think i can use somethings like this [Quick Tip: has_many :through => checkboxes](http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/)!

```
<% form_for @physician do -%>
  <% Speciality.all.each do |group| -%>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag :speciality_ids, speciality.id, @user.specialities.include?(speciality), :name => 'user[speciality_ids][]' -%>
      <%= label_tag :speciality_ids, speciality.name -%>
    </div>
  <% end -%>
  <%= submit_tag -%>
<% end -%>
```

But i don't know where can i put the speciality description ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are missing at least two relationship tables/models.

- SpecialtyDescription
- PhysicianSpecialityDescription

That way you can have the right connection between PhysicianSpeciality & PhysicianSpecialityDescription (PhysicianSpeciality_id, SpecialtyDescription_id) & SpecialtyDescription.

Answer (score 0):

Since the description is pending the creation of the join record in PhysicianSpecialty, I would just pass the description in as a text_area and sort it out pending the save of the Physician.

physicians_controller.rb

```
# i imagine ur update method would look kinda like this
def update
  @physician = Physician.find(params[:id])
  if @physician.update_attributes(params[:physician])
    physician_specialty = PhysicianSpecialty.find_by_specialty_id(:specialty_id => specialty.id)
    physician_specialty.update_attribute(:description, params[:description])
  else
    render :action => :edit
  end
end
```